# Best way to learn about Direct X

Tags: c++, directx

I want to begin looking at Direct X, but don't just want to try and throw myself into it. What are some good resources to get ones feet wet?

Comment: Do you have a preferred development language(s) or environment? E.g. C# using .Net 2.0, or C++ using Win32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend [Toymaker](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/getting_started.html)'s tutorials. Helped me greatly when I was first starting out with DX and was just as good as a reference later on.

The other thing to do would to set up some small projects that use DX that increase in difficulty as you go. If you'd like a starter list (from easy to hard):

- Compiling using DX libraries (I always remeber having trouble linking the libraries correctly in Visual Studio).
- Change background colour.
- See a model on-screen.
- Moving the model with input.
- A camera.
- Apply a texture to your model.
- Add multiple models to your scene.
- Add lighting.
- Create your a simple rectangle model and display a texture on it.

Get comfortable with all that and then have a look at shaders, advanced lighting and animation.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few books on directX, but there is so much freely available information on the web these days, I would just jump right in there.

A good place to start is just to do a youtube search for DirectX Tutorials.  In my opinion, this is a fun and interesting way to get started learning a new dev skill.